# USB mouse disconnects, and reconnection is not successful

Tags: usb, mouse

A Logitech Gaming Mouse G400 keeps disconnecting randomly. In the event reported below, it disconnected after 5.9 hours.

I have already:

- disassembled the mouse and [pulled the cord](https://askubuntu.com/a/1294767/362566) a few centimeters into the mouse
- blacklisted the mouse from [usb autosuspending](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Power_management#USB_autosuspend):

  ```
  # in /etc/udev/rules.d/50-usb_power_save.rules
  # blacklist for usb autosuspend
  ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="05c6", ATTR{idProduct}=="9205", GOTO="power_usb_rules_end"
  ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="usb", TEST=="power/control", ATTR{power/control}="auto"
  LABEL="power_usb_rules_end"
  ```
- set the Kernel boot parameters: [`acpi=off`](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingMouseDetection#In_case_your_mouse_stops_working_after_a_while) and [`usbcore.autosuspend=-1`](https://askubuntu.com/a/1154336/362566)

`/var/log/Xorg.0.log` reports

```
[ 21216.637] (II) config/udev: removing device Logitech Gaming Mouse G400
[ 21216.637] (II) event1  - Logitech Gaming Mouse G400: device removed
[ 21216.715] (II) UnloadModule: "libinput"
```

and `dmesg` reports

```
[21217.938985] usb 1-2: USB disconnect, device number 2
[21219.088604] usb usb1-port2: Cannot enable. Maybe the USB cable is bad?
[21219.216597] usb 1-2: new full-speed USB device number 7 using xhci_hcd
[21219.828647] usb 1-2: device descriptor read/64, error -71
[21220.756698] usb 1-2: device descriptor read/64, error -71
[21220.864727] usb usb1-port2: attempt power cycle
[21221.792756] usb 1-2: new full-speed USB device number 8 using xhci_hcd
[21221.792877] usb 1-2: Device not responding to setup address.
[21222.000895] usb 1-2: Device not responding to setup address.
[21222.208774] usb 1-2: device not accepting address 8, error -71
[21222.612804] usb 1-2: new full-speed USB device number 9 using xhci_hcd
[21222.612907] usb 1-2: Device not responding to setup address.
[21222.820919] usb 1-2: Device not responding to setup address.
[21223.028823] usb 1-2: device not accepting address 9, error -71
[21223.028867] usb usb1-port2: unable to enumerate USB device
```

Thicker part of the cable located in the bend has indeed deteriorated, but pulling the cord a few centimeters into the mouse seems to have fixed it; if I disconnect from the USB port and reconnect, the mouse work again. Moreover, even if there is still some problem with the cable, it seems from the `dmesg` report above that it goes back quickly to its place, and a reconnection is tried.

Why isn't the reconnection reported by `dmesg` successful, and what can be done about it?

Comment: If a USB cable is deteriorating on the inside, then you could be looking at an electrical short or a loss of power. Are you able to get a replacement cable? They shouldn’t be too expensive … 

Comment: As @Matigo noted, this is a hardware issue that is better dealt with sooner or you will end up with this: [Ubuntu 18.04 freezing frequently from past one month](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1224373/ubuntu-18-04-freezing-frequently-from-past-one-month).